# Stops snippets syncing between iPhone and Mac

Tags: ios, macos

A new feature in Mavericks in snippets. I use snippets on my iPhone and these are syncing to my Mac. How can I stop the snippets syncing to my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

The snippets sync through iCloud. The simplest solution is to just log out of iCloud, or disable iCloud's Documents & Data service in System Preferences, but it might not be ideal if you want to sync other iCloud data.